# How to use this type of body in a post request

Tags: json, go

I'm trying to send a post request to an API endpoint that uses this as its request body:

```
[
"username1",
"username2",
"username3"
]
```

Is there some sort of map I can do that allows this? This is an example code I have that doesn't help me, but I assume I need something like it.

```
values := map[string]string{"first": "John", "last": "Doe"}
```

Comment: We seen to need an array of string which would be `[]string{"john", "doe"}`

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Can you edit the question to explain better what you need, and what you've done so far?

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a json array, for that you would normally use a Go slice, and in this case specifically a slice of strings (`[]string`).

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    slice := []string{
        "username1",
        "username2",
        "username3",
    }
    data, err := json.Marshal(slice)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    resp, err := http.Post("https://example.com", "application/json", bytes.NewReader(data))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // ...

}
```